# Why the Convolution results in Python are shifted to left?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to Python and trying to perform a convolution between two 1D arrays. One array is quite large than the other array.

Convolution Conditions:

1. The convolution should take place only if the smaller array is completely over the larger array (i.e. `mode = 'valid'` in case of numpy convolution).
2. Smaller array must not be flipped for convolution

I tried to write my own `for-loop` to do the convolution as well as tried to use the `Numpy's Convolution()` but both the version produce the same results.

**MWE:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

larger_array = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0])
smaller_array = np.array([0,1,0])

result_length = larger_array.shape[0] - smaller_array.shape[0] + 1
convolution_result = np.zeros(result_length)

for i in range(result_length):
    convolution_result[i] = np.sum(larger_array[i:i + smaller_array.shape[0]] * smaller_array)

np_convolution_result = np.convolve(larger_array, smaller_array, mode='valid')

print("done!")
```

**Problem:**

The above code produces the results as plotted below. As seen in the plots, the convolution result is shifted to the left side. I mean the peak after convolution **SHOULD NOT** come before the peak of the original signal, right?

[image]

Comment: That is as expected. If the large array is 28 long and the small array is 3 long, then there are only 26 positions where the arrays completely overlap (as required by the "valid" parameter). So as that "1" in the centre of the smaller array tracks through the larger array, it copies all values from the larger array into the result *except* for the first and last value. If you want the large array and the result to be the same length, then use "same" instead of "valid".

Comment: @DaveRove: Thanks. If I use `same` then I guess the smaller array is getting flipped before convolution. The above plot is just a MWE. The actual function with which I want to convolve is a HRF function which looks like this ( https://rb.gy/53g0a ). In the HRF function, there is a dip towards the end (i.e. negative values) and when I convolve using `mode = same` then, the dip appears in the front of the convolution result.

Comment: Yes, you'll get border effects if you use `same`. If you use `valid`, then you can start the plot from a different position so that it lines up the way that you want, e.g.:       `plt.plot(1 + np.arange(len(np_convolution_result)), np_convolution_result)`